# Quarkus integration testing against running application with HTTPS

Tags: integration-testing, quarkus

I would like to use Integration-Tests with the Quarkus feature "testing against running application", as described in the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#executing-against-a-running-application).

I managed to make it work on local running instances, but I would like to test against our server which only accepts HTTPS requests.
Setting `quarkus.http.test-host` and `quarkus.http.test-port` as described in the documentation automatically leads to a HTTP request. I skimmed through the documentation of [all configuation options](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config), but could not find additional parameters that would help in this case.

Does anyone know how I could configure or customize the tests so that they would use HTTPS?

Comment: Did you try to set `quarkus.http.test-ssl-port` ?

Comment: Yes, but the configuation was ignored. The client still used HTTP.